# trying to add 2 events that happen in the same column in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Good day

I am trying to make both of the macros work in the same range since I want the drop down it that is created there to be able to check if there is a value in the column next to it get that rows values and also still be able to run the first macro. see picture attached since I don't think I am explaining properly what I want.

So in the picture in column A is set number. Column B has the dropdown where the first macro was implemented which enables it to be able to get values from column A and also be able to add a value to show 2+3 , I need it then to be able to get the values of stream C and actually add them in column C

attached is my current code and a picture of a example that doesn't necessarily work with the code just an example show what I mean.

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


  Dim Oldvalue As String
  Dim Newvalue As String

  Dim nommer As Integer
  Dim finder As Range


   On Error GoTo Exitsub
   If Target.Column = 3 Then   <------- here is macro 1
       If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
       GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
         Application.EnableEvents = False
         Newvalue = Target.Value
         Application.Undo
         Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & "+ " & Newvalue
        End If
      End If
    End If

   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J9")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("J9")
               Case "A": toets_my_ws
         End Select
     End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Exitsub:
   Application.EnableEvents = True

   If Target.Column = "3" Then <------- here is macro 2

        nommer = ActiveCell.Value
   Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
         Set finder = Range("B9:B40").Find(what:=ActiveCell.Value,LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = finder.Offset(0, 4).Value
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = finder.Offset(0, 6).Value
   End If



   End Sub
```

[image: example]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezM1G.png)

Comment: Side note: `If Target.Column = 3`... remove the quotes, since `Column` does not return a `String`.

Comment: It's really hard to look at code that isn't indented properly. I use https://rubberduckvba.com to fix my indentation automatically.

Comment: Thanks @HackSlash I will indent it quickly and have a look at rubberduck for next time

Comment: What is the criteria for running macro 1 vs macro 2? When would you use each one?

Comment: @HackSlash so this explanation will be based of the picture. Column B has a dropdown that gives me the options that are in Column A. If I select 1 for example it must put the number 1 in column b and add the value 1 next to it in column C. Then if I said in column B in the same cell to add Column A dropdown option 3 , Column B shows 1+3 which is macro 1,  macro 2 should then check to see the added number (3) and ad the value 3 from column C to The value 1 that was previously there. These 2 macros work separately but not when I try to make the work as I add values from my dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one event of this type as it works for the entire worksheet. So if you have multiple criteria for what happens when the worksheet changes you need to include all of that logic in the event. I have combined your logic in to one big thing but there is no way for me to tell if this was done correctly. You never use the variable `nommer` so that does nothing. It's also not clear what `toets_my_ws` is.

I would advise against using Worksheet change events as is slows down the worksheet considerably.

The better way to tackle this would be to use User Defined Functions (UDF). This way you can embed VBA in to a single cell without bogging down the whole sheet with logic every time you press a key.

HERE IS THE COMBINED LOGIC:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String

    Dim nommer As Integer
    Dim finder As Range

    If Target.Value = vbNullString Then GoTo Exitsub
    
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    If Target.Column = 3 Then                   
        nommer = ActiveCell.Value
        
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value
            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & "+ " & Newvalue
            End If
        End If
    Else
        Set finder = Range("B9:B40").Find(what:=ActiveCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = finder.Offset(0, 4).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = finder.Offset(0, 6).Value
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J9")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("J9")
        Case "A"
            toets_my_ws
        End Select
    End If
    
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

HERE IS INFORMATION ABOUT UDFS:

https://excelchamps.com/excel-user-defined-function/